# sql server full text search: what are the default word breakers in English?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, wordbreaker

Where can I find the list of default word breakers for English in sql server full text search?

Answer (score 1):

With the stored procedure `sys.dm_fts_parser` you can test given strings against the word breaker. The following query tests all ASCII chars from char(32) to char(255) and returns a list of currently active word breaker chars.

```sql
declare @i integer
declare @cnt integer
set @i=32
while @i<255
begin
  set @cnt=0
  select @cnt=COUNT(1) FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"word1'+CHAR(@i)+'word2"', 1033, 0, 0)
  if @cnt>1
  begin
  print CONCAT('ASCII ', @i, ': ', char(@i))
  end
  set @i=@i+1
end
```

Result:

```
ASCII 32:  
ASCII 33: !
ASCII 34: "
ASCII 35: #
ASCII 36: $
ASCII 37: %
ASCII 38: &
ASCII 40: (
ASCII 41: )
ASCII 42: *
ASCII 43: +
... and so on ...
```

Source: https://stuart-moore.com/generating-a-list-of-full-text-word-breakers-for-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Neutral word breakers (white space and punctuation) + Locale specific values.  So, it would depend on which English Locale is running.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The list of languages which have word breakers associated with them can be obtained by running  the following query -

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_languages;
```

I am not sure if there's a stored-proc or an internal table which shows you the .dll file associated with each language but that can be looked up under the following registry key -

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\{SQL Instance Name}\MSSearch\CLSID\
```

The language mappings for each CLSID is stored in MSSearch\Language.

Comment: I believe the SP you're looking for which shows the associated .dll is EXEC sp_help_fulltext_system_components 'wordbreaker';